# Create a lot of Symlinks with pwd and regular expressions and space in path

Tags: linux, terminal, script, symbolic-link, pwd

I'm trying to create a script in order to keep the files with the same extension in a folder separated from the rest. In particular, I want a script that, executed in a folder, create soft links of all .tex files and put them in a subfolder "sources".

I know that `ln` copes well with regular expressions, and `$PWD` or `$(pwd)` returns the path to the current folder. So I tried to execute

```
ln -s $PWD/*.tex ./sources/
```

in my folder, but soon I realized that in my path there was a folder with spaces in it, that `ln` reads as multiple files. So I tried with

```
ln -s '$PWD'/*.tex ./sources/
```

and

```
ln -s '$PWD/*.tex' ./sources/
```

but in both cases, the script produces a single file named `*.tex` in my `sources` folder. Following some post, I tried to modify the spaces in the path like these

```
ln -s $(printf "%q\n" "$PWD")/*.tex sources/

ln -s '$(printf "%q\n" "$PWD")'/*.tex sources/

ln -s '$(printf "%q\n" "$PWD")/*.tex' sources/
```

but the output was the same (with the difference of an additional character `\`).

Help?

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt should work. Does it not? What does it do instead?

`*` substitutes with all matching filenames, but does *not* perform splitting at internal spaces afterwards.

"I know that ln copes well with regular expressions" – this is wrong. First, it's shell patterns that you see here, not regular expressions. Second, it's not `ln` coping with them but your shell (typically `bash`) prior to launching `ln` or any other command.

Comment: the first attempt produces multiple files according to the spaces in the path:

if, for example, the folder is called "my files", then the command `ln -s $PWD/*.tex sources/ ` produces two files that are named `my` and `*.tex` disregarding of what is inside the folder

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood the situation. Thought it was the .tex files that had spaces in their names. You should surround `$PWD` by double quotes: `"$PWD"/*`

Comment: U should write that  in your answer